# Stripe java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid Setup Intent client secret:

Tags: stripe-payments

E/App: Got error:
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid Setup Intent client secret: pi_3LtYhHAZTS98jCaY3NVtpCAW_secret_yUvzN3ytPIexEVJGtOzvQCSOM
at com.stripe.android.model.SetupIntent$ClientSecret.

Here i added my all codes of java class and php api for the test but i got this above error on the same code so plz do my help

```js
paymentSheet = new PaymentSheet(this, this::onPaymentSheetResult);

Fuel.INSTANCE.post("my api link",null).responseString(new Handler<String>() {
            @Override
            public void success(String s) {
                try {
                    final JSONObject result = new JSONObject(s);
                    customerConfig = new PaymentSheet.CustomerConfiguration(
                            result.getString("customer"),
                            result.getString("ephemeralKey")
                    );
                    paymentIntentClientSecret = result.getString("paymentIntent");
                    PaymentConfiguration.init(getContext().getApplicationContext(), result.getString("publishableKey"));
                } catch (JSONException e) { /* handle error */ }
            }

            @Override
            public void failure(@NotNull FuelError fuelError) { /* handle error */ }
        });
```

```css
if(isset($action) && $action='pay' && isset($amount)){
    \Stripe\Stripe::setApiKey('sk_test_qrdTKAz2kaeZEPZHK2OdrNpn');
  // Use an existing Customer ID if this is a returning customer.
  $userid = $_GET['u'];
  $query_usr = "SELECT * FROM tbl_user WHERE user_id = '$userid'";
  $r_usr = $conn->query($query_usr);
  $user = $r_usr->fetch_assoc();
  if($user['stripe_customer'] == NULL){
    $customer = \Stripe\Customer::create([
        'name' => $user['user_name'],
        'email' => $user['user_email']    
    ]);
    $customer_id = $customer->id;
    $conn->query("UPDATE tbl_user SET stripe_customer = '$customer_id' WHERE user_id = $userid");
  }
  else{
      $customer_id = $user['stripe_customer'];
  }
  
  $ephemeralKey = \Stripe\EphemeralKey::create(
  [
    'customer' => $customer_id,
  ],
  [
    'stripe_version' => '2020-08-27',
  ]);
  $paymentIntent = \Stripe\PaymentIntent::create([
    'amount' => 1099,
    'currency' => 'cad',
    'customer' => $customer_id,
    'automatic_payment_methods' => [
      'enabled' => 'true',
    ],
  ]);
  
  $si = \Stripe\SetupIntent::create([
        'customer' => $customer_id
    ]);
    
    

    
    
    
    
  
        
    $response['paymentIntent'] = $paymentIntent->client_secret;
    $response['setupIntent'] = $si->client_secret;
    $response['ephemeralKey']= $ephemeralKey->secret;
    $response['customer']= $customer_id;
    $response['publishableKey'] = 'pk_test_0aSL6prHXE16hsokTWYKk8Gz';
    echo json_encode($response);  
   
    // return $response->withJson([
    //     'paymentIntent' => $paymentIntent->client_secret,
    //     'ephemeralKey' => $ephemeralKey->secret,
    //     'customer' => $customer_id,
    //     'publishableKey' => 'pk_live_8mBL0Iji2oVDpgmBAVwPiicC'
    // ])->withStatus(200);

}
else
{

    $response['error']=TRUE;
    $response['error_msg']="Required Parameters are missing";
    echo json_encode($response);

}
```

```html
private void presentPaymentSheet() {
        final PaymentSheet.Configuration configuration = new PaymentSheet.Configuration.Builder("!2min, Inc.")
                .customer(customerConfig)
                // Set `allowsDelayedPaymentMethods` to true if your business can handle payment methods
                // that complete payment after a delay, like SEPA Debit and Sofort.
                .allowsDelayedPaymentMethods(true).build();
        paymentSheet.presentWithSetupIntent(
                paymentIntentClientSecret,
                configuration
        );
    }

    private void onPaymentSheetResult(final PaymentSheetResult paymentSheetResult) {
        if (paymentSheetResult instanceof PaymentSheetResult.Canceled) {
            Log.d("cantag","Canceled");
        } else if (paymentSheetResult instanceof PaymentSheetResult.Failed) {
            Log.e("App", "Got error: ", ((PaymentSheetResult.Failed) paymentSheetResult).getError());
        } else if (paymentSheetResult instanceof PaymentSheetResult.Completed) {
            // Display for example, an order confirmation screen
            Log.d("tcmp","Completed");
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based off the error message, you should be passing in a SetupIntent's client_secret - a SetupIntent id starts with `si_` . However, you're passing in a PaymentIntent's client_secret - a PaymentIntent id starts with `pi_`

If you intend to use a PaymentIntent, you should follow the guide here : https://stripe.com/docs/payments/accept-a-payment?platform=android

If you intend to use a SetupIntent, you should follow the guide here : https://stripe.com/docs/payments/save-and-reuse?platform=android&ui=payment-sheet

Comment: so how i do with si_

Comment: i did the 1st one of above but the issue is same

Comment: can you update your original ask to include your code? Having the error message alone isn't sufficient to troubleshoot

Comment: Here i added my all codes of java class and php api for the test but i got this above error on the same code so plz do my help

Comment: you're using `paymentSheet.presentWithSetupIntent` but you're passing in `paymentIntentClientSecret`. 

If you're attempting to save and reuse the card later : you should be returning the SetupIntent's client secret in your response and use it with `paymentSheet.presentWithSetupIntent`

If you're attempting to accept a payment : you should be using `paymentSheet.presentWithPaymentIntent` (not `paymentSheet.presentWithSetupIntent`)